# Function that parses string and sets the variable accordingly

Tags: c++

I want to do an simple script language in C++

After calling

```
string statement = "Set anObject.subObject.PublicVariable 10";
execute(statement);
```

Execute would do

```
anObject.subObject.PublicVariable = 10;
```

How can I do something like that?
I have no idea (well, except switch/case that handles every variable - but this is too inefficent and stupid) how to do this.

Comment: Nothing, yet - but I have tried to Google my answer, found parser creators like Yacc and Bison. But that hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Parsing is the easy part here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to be using the base command of `set` then you can do something like this possibly...

```
class BaseClass {
    vector<string> objects;
    vector<void*> locationOfObjects;
    ...
}
```

and then once a command is submitted interate through the string vector in that class and find the position of the object that you are trying to set (for subobjects you could loop through the string continuing to find the location of the target object to be set) and then set that object to be a certain value. Note that every class would need to be a subclass of BaseClass so that every object or subobject could have the objects be iterated through.

Comment: But first, I have to fill this lookup table with pointers and strings, and later cast from (void*) to the type - definitely better that than switch/case.

Comment: I would recommend replacing the two vectors with a `map<string, void*>` .  And then split that map into `map<string, int*>` and `map<string, double*>`, etc for type safety

Answer (score 2):

I took this as an exercise in Boost Spirit.

---

Here is the older, simpler (more realistic...) sample:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi=boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px=boost::phoenix;

std::map<std::string, int> variables;
static void record(const std::string& name, int value) 
    { variables[name] = value; };

int main()
{
    std::string input/* = "Set anObject.subObject.PublicVariable 10"*/;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

        if (!qi::phrase_parse(f,l, 
                "Set" >> 
                (
                     qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +(!qi::space >> (qi::alnum | qi::char_("_."))) ] ] >>
                     qi::int_
                ) [ 
                     px::bind(record, qi::_1, qi::_2) 
                  ],
            qi::space))
        {
            std::cerr << "fail: '" << input << "'" << std::endl;
        }

        if (f!=l)
            std::cerr << "unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto kv : variables)
        std::cout << kv.first << ":\t" << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

For input `Set anObject.subObject.PublicVariable 10`, will print:

```
anObject.subObject.PublicVariable:  10
```

### Update

I threw in the kitchen sink (**[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zf34n64t)**), in case you actually wanted a full blown hierarchy of type:

```
struct object
{
    std::string name;
    // non-key:
    mutable variant_t value;
    mutable std::set<object> children;
    // ...
};
```

This demo now supports values of integer, quoted string and floating point type, hence the `variant_t` is defined as

```
typedef boost::optional<boost::variant<std::string, double, int> > variant_t;
```

For the input

```
Set bla.blo 123
Set veryLong.subObject.stringVal "hello"
Set veryLong.subObject 31415926E-7
Set answer 42
Set bla.blo "world"
```

The output is

```
name: <globals>
{
    name: answer (value: 42)
    {
    }
    name: bla
    {
        name: blo (value: world)
        {
        }
    }
    name: veryLong
    {
        name: subObject (value: 3.14159)
        {
            name: stringVal (value: hello)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scripting language to hold it's own variables:

```
struct variable {
    std::map<std::string, variable> children;
    int value;

    variable() : value(0) {}
    variable(int rhs) : value(rhs) {}
    variable(const variable& rhs) : children(rhs.children), value(rhs.value) {}

    operator=(int rhs) {value = rhs; return *this;
    variable& operator[](const std::string& rhs) {return children[rhs];}
};
```

If you want the scripting language to modify the C++ variables, you'll have to register them like DanZimm shows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably can't.

If I guess corretly you want the "script" to search for the object named `anObject`, get its field `subObject` and set its field `PublicVariable` to 10.

Of course you can try really hard to make the user *believe*, the code does this, but once you compiled a C++ program, variable and function names are gone, they become mere addresses (Well there are things called debug symbols, but thats not really c++ ...), and Types only exist for the compiler, and not for the running program. so if you hoped for something like `eval()` in action script..., nope, there aren't any!